# Javascript code that will display full url of a page

Tags: javascript

In this below codes, i want a script that will display the full url of a page inside where there is FULL URL! Please help me! Note, my site is just an xhtml site(Wapka.Mobi)

```
var disqus_url = 'FULL URL';
(function () {
    var dsq = document.createElement('script');
    dsq.type = 'text/javascript';
    dsq.async = true;
    dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
})();
```

Comment: This question is lacking in the research department https://www.google.ca/search?q=how+to+get+full+url+of+page&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=NLtzU9qVGIKN8QeF1oDQDg#channel=fflb&q=get+page+url+with+javascript&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&safe=off

Comment: You can use `document.documentURI` or `document.URL` to get the full document location.

The only main difference between them is that `document.documentURI` will be available on **every types** of documents (e.g. xml) while `document.URL` will works on **HTML** documents only.

Moreover, it has been introduced from the DOM4 specification (See the MDN for more informations about it : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.documentURI).

In case of doubt, you might prefer using `document.documentURI`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution will be:

```
var disqus_url = window.location;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var disqus_url = document.location.href;
```

Comment: for crossbrowser safety one should use window.location http://www.w3.org/TR/Window/#window-location